# Installing boost library on windows not working (no console output at all)

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to install the boost library on windows 10, the first few steps are working:

- Downloading the library
- Unzipping
- Bootstrapping

But then when trying to run b2.exe or bjam.exe there is nothing happening (except high CPU load), but no console output whatsoever, not even an error.

I can't find any explanation or help on the internet, maybe some of you got an idea

Comment: How long have you waited? Maybe the output is broken but the compilation works.

Comment: Around 30-60 minutes but I'll start it again and run it over night!

Comment: You can also have a clue as to what the process is doing through Windows' resource monitor, which shows file activity.

Comment: @Quentin  Thanks for now, I will investigate what is happening! By the way: there is no output folder created/filled (at least as I've seen)

Comment: Is this for Visual Studio? If so did you run it from the appropriate Visual Studio command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

Since you've mentioned you're working on Windows, maybe Visual Studio is appropriate for your choice. In such case, you can use vcpkg tool to install boost. Check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/vcpkg?view=vs-2017).

Once the tool is installed, it's really easy to install various libraries and they will automatically be detected in your Visual Studio projects. To install boost simply run `vcpkg install boost:x64-windows`.